# Python imap-tools 'MailMessage' object has no attribute 'reply_to'

Tags: python, imap

I'm using the [imap-tools](https://pypi.org/project/imap-tools/) library and I have the following error when trying to access message.reply_to :

'MailMessage' object has no attribute 'reply_to'

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: maybe it creates `reply_to` only if it exists in mail. You should check if this mail has header `reply to`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 1):

I added reply_to. Update lib version.

(imap_tools author)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution :

```
pattern = "^[^<]+<([^>]+).*"
search = re.search(pattern, str(msg.obj['Reply-To']))
if search:
    reply_to = search.group(1)
else:
    reply_to = ''
```

Comment: did you check if email had header 'Reply-To' when you got error ? Maybe you needed simple `try/except` to catch error.